# Unable to Compile Hplip-3.10.9

Tags: compiler-errors, installation, printers

I have all the required dependencies for the compile. Running `./configure` finishes without errors. But after running `make`, it says:

"In file included from prnt/hpcups/HPCupsFilter.h:34,
                 from prnt/hpcups/HPCupsFilter.cpp:31:
prnt/hpcups/CommonDefinitions.h:41: fatal error: cups/raster.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [hpcups-HPCupsFilter.o] Error 1".

What went wrong? I really need to get my printer set up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced the same problem today. I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 & I solved it by installing libcupsimage2-dev.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to compile. But now how do I setup my printer. I installed the compiled program but what do I do next?

Comment: You'd need to "make install" if you haven't already done so. I ran "/usr/local/bin/hp-setup -i" but wasn't sure whether it really did anything for me at all, maybe this step wasn't necessary but I can't remember. After I tried that I ran "/usr/local/bin/hp-toolbox" and I could print after that.